# Select where time is between -1 and 5 minutes of specified time

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I want to select rows from a mySQL database where the current time is between -1 and 5 minutes relative to the 'endTime' field in the row.

The 'endTime' field is the type 'time'.

Here is my current, non working code:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   endTime
            BETWEEN
                DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MINUTE)
            AND
                DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just swap your usages of endTime and NOW().

Comment: It still won't work -- it just returns zero rows. Is it because i'm feeding it a time instead of a datetime?

Comment: I think so. Add TIME() if you just want the TIME component.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it myself:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   endTime
            > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
AND     endTime
            < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Posting this in case someone else finds it useful.

Comment: Looking at the solution, your question seems confusing. You said, *‘…where the current time is between -1 and 5 minutes relative to the 'endTime' field…’*, but both in your question and in your answer the code is looking for `endTime` between -1 and 5 minutes relative to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late- but this would work and be more succinct:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE endTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```